# The Hazelcast client from the Spring Boot/Eureka code samples does not work

Tags: spring-boot, hazelcast, netflix-eureka

Had an attempt to use the samples provided here https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/hazelcast-integration/springboot-eureka-partition-groups. Everything goes well, meaning the eureka server registers correctly as many hazelcast clusters as started, the eureka client works fine, but the my-hazelcast-client sample is not able to find any of the service instances registered within Eureka. The last logged line from this client is:

```
discoverNodes(): Hazelcast lookup to Eureka: start
```

While debugging, I see that:

- **my-eureka-client** is autowiring a `org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaDiscoveryClient` containing as eurekaClient a `org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient` object
- **my-hazelcast-client** (the faulty one) gets a `com.sun.proxy.$Proxy` object with toString() returning "Collecting data...".

Comment: Apparently, It stopped working after this commit so as a workaround you can switch back to 3.8 for the time being. 
https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/commit/f45d492ae29ef2033b47dc704db2f04d7839dcf2#diff-7df91cbbfcc10f3d306b79e924845aac

This is the follow-up github issue.
https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/issues/225

Comment: indeed, it works with version 3.8! Thanks a lot. Case closed for me.